# Java convert string to string array by spaces

Tags: java, arrays, string

I would like to convert string to string array.. I have done something like this:

```
String name = "name";
String[] letters = name.split("(?<=.)");
System.out.println("letters = " + Arrays.toString(letters));
```

But now I want something like this:

```
String name = "John Mark Lester Andrew Todd";
```

To print array like this:

```
[John, Mark, Lest, Andrew, Todd]
```

So I want to look for spaces in my string and then put them into a string array. Do you have ideas to do this? Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: this print exactly what do you want `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name.split(" ")));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) your string on `whitespace`.

```
String[] words = name.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split()` and create an array.

```
String name = "John Mark Lester Andrew Todd";
String[] names=name.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 2):

What ever criteria or letter on the basis of which a string is to be split,that need to be provided under

```
  string.split(" ");
```

so,u can try using these updated code:::

```
 String name = "John Mark Lester Andrew Todd";
 String[] letters = name.split(" ");
 System.out.println("letters = " + Arrays.toString(letters));
```

and the ouput will be::

```
  letters = [John, Mark, Lester, Andrew, Todd]
```

And for better understanding for splitting the strings in java,you can go to this link.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

Comment: I think its better to use "\\s+" instead of " ".

Comment: We've all been there bro.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Comment: You forgot to mention this about `StringTokenizer` - *StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.*

Comment: My bad. The `split` method is even mentioned in the docs. Anyway just pointed out that this is also possible. It IS deprecated though.

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible is to split on all whitespace:

```
String names = "John  \t\t  Mark  Lester \n  Andrew Todd \r";

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names.split("\\s+")));
```

Outputs:

```
[John, Mark, Lester, Andrew, Todd]
```

`\\s+` is regex for "any length of any whitespace characters". Similarly if you only care about spaces:

```
String names = "John  Mark  Lester   Andrew Todd  ";

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names.split(" +")));
```

(Outputs same as above.)

Of course both of those will split single spaces too.

Comment: you changed the actual value of `names`, and OP want the output in format `[John, Mark, Lest, Andrew, Todd]`. but I agree the use of `"\\s+"` instead of `" "`

Comment: @RafaEl All I did was mangle it to show the regex handles any whitespace. That would be a stupid reason to downvote. The regex splits the OP's single space input too.

Comment: then you might want to explain in the answer, why you add `\t\t`, `\n`, `\r` there.

Comment: @RafaEl Because *they are whitespace characters*. \t is a tab, \n is a new line and \r is a carriage return.

Comment: @RafaEl I think it's pretty clear what the regex does. I think somebody just had a vacuous reason for voting. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Im not talking about the regex. Im talking about why you change the `names` value. I've been in the same situation before, and thats how I got the _Peer Pressure_ badge

Comment: @RafaEl "All whitespace". Seriously, I should not have to explain what a \n is. It's the kind of thing where if somebody *really* doesn't know they can open Google or legitimately ask. It is not a reason to downvote and **not** a reason to delete an answer as in Peer Pressure. But it really doesn't matter. I only wrote an answer because I was surprised nobody had suggested this. Now it's been suggested.

Comment: Again, thats not my point. its like, _"Q:Tiger, lion, and giraffe are in which animal category?"_. _"A:Tiger, lion, giraffe and kangaroo are mammals"_ where the proper answer expected is  _"Tiger, lion and giraffe are mammals."_ or if you want to add something, _"Tiger, lion and giraffe are mammals. For your information, kangaroo is also a mammals"_. See the difference. I am sorry for arguing with just a small matter maybe, but it really bother me just now. I didn't mean to argue your answer, but just the way you present it. Peace

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
String values=Arrays.toString(name.split(" "));

or

String values[] = name.split("\\s")
```